# ArrayList and Formatter not behaving as expected

Tags: java, windows, arraylist, formatter

I have two Arraylists, one contains an entire list of objects, the second contains objects to remove from the first list.

When I remove the objects from the first list and when I output those objects to a file using a Formatter, nothing is written to the file. However if I output the objects from the first Arraylist, without removing any objects, all of those objects appear in the file.

For example:-

```
for(Invoice inv : tempStore)
{
  if(invoiceLines.contains(inv))invoiceLines.remove(inv);
}

//for each invoice in the ArrayList
for(Invoice invoice : invoiceLines)
{
  output.format("%"+this.spec.getLength("XXXX")+"s\t",checkString(invoice.getInvoiceDate()));}
```

gives me no output, however doing just:-

```
//for each invoice in the ArrayList
for(Invoice invoice : invoiceLines)
{
  output.format("%"+this.spec.getLength("XXXX")+"s\t",checkString(invoice.getInvoiceDate()));}
```

gives me output information, when manually debugging the application the arraylist (the one with the objects removed), does contain objects still and those objects contain the correct values. It's almost as if the Arraylist, once objects are removed is losing the pointers in memory.

Any ideas? Unfortunately I can't give much in the way of specific code, however ask any questions and I will try to answer as best as I can. The language is Java and I'm using Java compliance 1.5 in the SDK.

Comment: I'd use a debugger and check that your `invoiceLines` is not empty before iterating and printing in case 1.

Comment: Already done so, hence the comment of when using a debugger the object are present. When I say manually debugging, I mean in the sense of stepping through the code and checking the variables, rather than using automated tests I have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Formatter.flush()` and `Formatter.close()` need to be called at the end of output.

Comment: It must have been pure luck that when not deleting the items from the Arraylist that the buffer was full, thereby causing all of the objects to be written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the error you can add more output (as console output or using a Logger) on the removing operation:

```
System.out.println("Items before removal: " + invoiceLines.size());
for(Invoice inv : tempStore)
{
  if(invoiceLines.contains(inv)) {
    invoiceLines.remove(inv);
    System.out.println("removed " + inv + ". Items left: " + invoiceLines.size());
  }    

}
```

If there are more than items removed during one iteration, you want to check the equals() and hashCode() Implementation of the Invoice class.
If you have your own implementation, make sure you followed the [Object.equals()-Contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: The equals and hashCode implementation are Object.equals() and Object.hashCode(). Those methods are not overridden in the class definition. The number of items removed from the ArrayList are correct and the items remaining is also correct, more than one item is not removed from the Arraylist per iteration.